# Prevent GStreamer from changing camera format

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2, gstreamer-1.0

Running GStreamer pipeline that feeds from `v4l2src` element may change camera format implicitly.

Here is an example (also note that `/dev/video0` is everywhere implied).

One of my cameras supports these formats

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x800
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x1024
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
```

The current format is

```
$ v4l2-ctl --get-fmt-video
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 1280
    Size Image        : 614400
    Colorspace        : Default
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
    Flags             :
```

If I just run this pipeline

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

This will change the current format (before the pipeline is run, but it will also be left in that state) to

```
$ v4l2-ctl --get-fmt-video
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1280/1024
    Pixel Format      : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 2560
    Size Image        : 2621440
    Colorspace        : Default
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
    Flags             :
```

And this is not what I want. What I want is for GStreamer to use already set format and not change it. How I can accomplish that *programmatically* (`gst-launch-1.0` was just an example, I'm primarily interested in doing this in code)?

Answer (score 0):

When the `caps-negotiation` between pipeline elements is taking place, the first match will be used. Most probably it is not what you set up.

To enforce given format, define caps explicitly:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src ! videoconvert ! \
video/x-raw,format=YVYU,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! \
videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

To set the caps in C/C++, use:

```
gst_util_set_object_arg(element, "caps", "video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, format=YUY2");
```